# API creation: Login user without login URL

Tags: php, api, authentication

I'm creating an API for an IOS app which will retrieve some data of a user on a website. 
However, I'm not pro with PHP and I need to log a user on the website which doesn't have a login url like: ....php?user=abcd&pass=efgh/

I use HTTP requests to perform this log. My goal is to retrieve some data from this website.

Here is the code of the login form:

```
<form id="login-form" class="body" action="login" method="post">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" for="username">Identifiant</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Mot de passe</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                                               required/>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            <input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" name="_csrf"
                                                   value="a405b265-404f-4305-b6be-594e07b09ff4"/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"> Connexion </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Complete code: https://pastebin.com/Fz2uyDap

In this website there is no visible url... I tried to inspect the website network while loging in but nothing.
Here is the website login URL: https://auth.myefrei.fr/uaa/login
 Any idea? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: please post the complete form html code

Comment: It is using `POST` so the data is not sent through the URL. Use `$_POST` and it should be there.

Comment: Note also that the site uses CSRF tokens to prevent exactly what you're trying to do...

Comment: @Alex Howansky So there is no way to to this?

Comment: It should doable, but you can't just make a single post to log in. You'll have to make one request to grab the token and then another to pass it back.

Comment: I'm using Alamfore to make requests. If you know this library, is it possible to get the CSRF token with it? Thanks for the help btw.